# setScaleX/setScaleY (Cocos2D)

Tags: ios, api, cocos2d-iphone

I just wanted to clarify something here for Cocos2D, does setScaleX/and setScale Y adjust the width and height of the object?

I have googled for the documentation for Cocos2D but I didn't see it so I just wanted to clarify here.

So would something like this make the width 35?

```
[sprite1 setScaleX:35 / sprite1.contentSize.width];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want CCNodes scale property for both x and y:

- http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/latest-stable/interface_c_c_node.html#a9c00de8556f267b63055ebd9e55f2415

If you want to do it gradually use one of these actions:

- http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/latest-stable/interface_c_c_scale_by.html
- http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/latest-stable/interface_c_c_scale_to.html